# Creating a new column using info from another df

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a new column based off information from another data table.

df1

```
Loc Time   Wage
1    192    1
3    192    2
1    193    3
5    193    3
7    193    5
2    194    7
```

df2

```
Loc  City
1    NYC
2    Miami
3    LA
4    Chicago
5    Houston
6    SF
7    DC
```

desired output:

```
Loc Time   Wage  City
1    192    1    NYC
3    192    2    LA
1    193    3    NYC
5    193    3    Houston
7    193    5    DC
2    194    7    Miami
```

The actual dataframes vary quite largely in terms of row numbers, but its something along the lines of that. I think this might be achievable through `.map` but I haven't found much documentation for that online. `join` doesn't really seem to fit this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` is exactly what you need. Try running this in the `spark-shell`

```
import spark.implicits._

val col1 = Seq("loc", "time", "wage")
val data1 = Seq((1, 192, 1), (3, 193, 2), (1, 193, 3), (5, 193, 3), (7, 193, 5), (2, 194, 7))
val col2 = Seq("loc", "city")
val data2 = Seq((1, "NYC"), (2, "Miami"), (3, "LA"), (4, "Chicago"), (5, "Houston"), (6, "SF"), (7, "DC"))

val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data1).toDF(col1: _*)
val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data2).toDF(col2: _*)

val outputDf = df1.join(df2, Seq("loc"))  // join on the column "loc"

outputDf.show()
```

This will output

```
+---+----+----+-------+
|loc|time|wage|   city|
+---+----+----+-------+
|  1| 192|   1|    NYC|
|  1| 193|   3|    NYC|
|  2| 194|   7|  Miami|
|  3| 193|   2|     LA|
|  5| 193|   3|Houston|
|  7| 193|   5|     DC|
+---+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: Yeah I worked it out earlier,I was thinking inner join which kinda messed it up - really appreciate the answer though!